# Python extension compilation error

Tags: python, c, numpy

I followed a tutorial on C extensions for Python, but when at compilation, I got this error message

```
>python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    import numpy.distutils.misc_util
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils.misc_util
```

I run on Windows10 with VS2008 C++ compiler (as recommanded to compile Python extensions) and Anaconda. When I try to load the module in a python script, I got no error as numpy is well installed.

Comment: Is the python path setup correctly in your command-prompt?

Comment: Yes, but I just found that the python command target is for python 2.7 install folder, whereas pip destination folder is for anaconda.... so numpy is not installed for python 2.7 distro